# Efficiently swap values between related columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02',
                   '2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02')),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1037, 1037),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2037, 2037),
  resp_A = c(3,1,2,4),
  resp_B = c(2,4,3,1),
  connect_A = c(6,2,5,3),
  connect_B = c(5,3,6,2),
  test_A = c(3,9,0,0),
  test_B = c(1,1,1,1)
)
```

I want to swap the values between related columns such that X_A is now X_B and X_B is now X_A. I want to do this across all the columns with _A and _B appended to the column names **except** PID_A and PID_A (e.g. only `resp`, `connect`, `test`). In reality, I have many more of such columns, but I have simplified the dataset to these three variables for example's sake.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02',
                   '2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02')),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1037, 1037),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2037, 2037),
  resp_A = c(2,4,3,1),
  resp_B = c(3,1,2,4),
  connect_A = c(5,3,6,2),
  connect_B = c(6,2,5,3),
  test_A = c(1,1,1,1),
  test_B = c(3,9,0,0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I actually want to leave `PID_A` and `PID_B` out of this operation. I have changed the question accordingly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than mess around with the data, I think the most efficient thing is going to be to change the column names.

We can use [`stringr::str_replace()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html), which we can provide a function instead of a fixed replacement. The function will say: if the column name ends in `"_A"`, make it end in `"_B"` and vice-versa (unless the name starts with `"PID"`).

```r
col_order <- names(example) # In case you need to preserve order
names(example) <- stringr::str_replace(
    names(example),
    "(?<!^PID)_[AB]$",
    \(x) ifelse(x == "_A", "_B", "_A")
)
```

If the column order is important you can switch back to the original order. This will not create a copy of the data.

```r
example  <- example[col_order]
#         date PID_A PID_B resp_A resp_B connect_A connect_B test_A test_B
# 1 2001-01-01  1091  2091      2      3         5         6      1      3
# 2 2001-01-02  1091  2091      4      1         3         2      1      9
# 3 2001-01-01  1037  2037      3      2         6         5      1      0
# 4 2001-01-02  1037  2037      1      4         2         3      1      0
```

##### Explanation of the regex pattern

We can use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match all column names ending in `"_A"` or `"_B"`, unless immediately preceded by the start of the string followed by `"PID"`.

[image]

[Regex visualiser](https://regex-vis.com/?r=%28%3F%3C%21PID%29_%5BAB%5D%24)